# Completion Block of concurrent NSOperation not being called everytime

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I would like to run a concurrent NSOperation. For this reason, I have extended the NSOperation class and overridden the start and finish methods. It looks something like this:

```
#import "AVFrameConversionOP.h"


@implementation AVFrameConversionOP //extends NSOperation

- (void)start
{

    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
    _isFinished = NO;
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];

    // Begin
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
    _isExecuting = YES;
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];

    if (_isCancelled == YES) {
        NSLog(@"** OPERATION CANCELED **");
        [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
        _isFinished = YES;
        [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
        return;
    } 

    [self performTask];
    [self finish];

}

- (void)finish
{

    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];

    _isExecuting = NO;
    _isFinished = YES;

    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];

    NSLog(@"operationfinished, _isFinished is %d", _isFinished);

    if (_isCancelled == YES)
    {
        NSLog(@"** OPERATION CANCELED **");
    }
}

- (void)performTask
{
    //The task is performed here
    sleep(0.1); //This is just for demonstration purposes
}
@end
```

I have defined the completion block for this NSOperation in the main view controller in the viewDidLoad method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

NSLog(@"viewDidLoad!");
[super viewDidLoad];

static int counter = 0;


_frameConvOP = [[AVFrameConversionOP alloc] init]; //Initializing the modified NSOperation class
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
_frameConvOP.completionBlock = ^ {
    counter++;
    //NSLogs don't seem to work here
    /*if(counter>1){
         exit(-1); //Never happens because counter only ever becomes =1
    }*/

};
[[VideoPreviewer instance] setNSOperation:_frameConvOP]; //This is where I send the NSOperation object to the class where I'm using it

}
```

I'm starting the NSOperation by doing `[frameConvOP start]` inside of a loop. It is called continuously every time a frame is decoded, so that is to say it is called very often. I can see that the `finish` and `start` methods of the NSOperation are being called frequently through the logs. And the functions inside these methods are also being correctly called. However, the NSLogs inside the completion blocked aren't logged. I put an exit(-1) inside the completion block and the app crashed, but the NSLogs never show up. So I put a static counter in there and it only increments to 1. So the completion block is only being called once.

Can anyone explain why the completion block is being called only once? Is it because of the way I'm (incorrectly) handling the KVO for `_isFinished` and `_isExecuting`? The completion block should be called when `_isFinished` is set to YES and as far as I can see, I am doing that in the finish block. And the finish block is being called quite frequently as it should be.

Any help, guidance or direction is appreciated. Please let me know if I have made any errors or if I have been less-than-clear in the post.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

From the [`NSOperation` class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/):

> An operation object is a single-shot object—that is, it executes its task once and cannot be used to execute it again.

You are not allowed to invoke `-start` multiple times on a single operation object.

Another thing, in your `-finish` method, you need to properly nest the `-willChange...` and `-didChange...` calls. That is, you need to call `-didChange...` in the reverse order of the `-willChange...` calls:

```
[self willChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
[self willChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];

_isExecuting = NO;
_isFinished = YES;

[self didChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
[self didChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I made the changes to the nesting as you suggested. How is that the start and finish methods are being successfully called multiple times and it is only the completion block that is called once? And isn't the purpose of setting your own start and finish methods so that you can call the task repeatedly?

Comment: I don't know how it can be clearer: the implementation of `NSOperation` is built around the rule that it can only be run once. It is not at all surprising that the completion block will only be called once. (The docs actually say that for current versions of iOS, it is cleared once it is called.) The purpose of implementing your own `-start` method is to customize what the operation does. It has nothing to do with running it repeatedly, since that's illegal. Implementing `-finish` is irrelevant, since `NSOperation` itself doesn't use that method. That's specific to your class.